# SQL sub query not being grouped

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am having some trouble with this sub query, I am trying to count the amount of columns called id where sStatus='Open' but grouped with the sCompany. As of now its just returning a count of all id's where sStatus is open for the entire table.

Maybe a sub query isn't the best way to handle this and I may need a join? I have tried not using a sub query and just using a count, however the WHERE clause for sStatus='Closed' would just make it return 0.

```
SELECT Sum(nQuotetotal) AS nsales,
       sCompany,
       Max(dtFirstClosed) AS dtMostRecent,
       (SELECT Count(id)
              FROM   customer_quotes
              WHERE  sStatus='Open') AS nOpenQuotes
FROM   customer_quotes
WHERE  sQuoteType='cam'
AND    bDeleted=0
AND    sStatus='Closed'
AND    dtFirstClosed BETWEEN " + getDate + ' GROUP BY sCompany ORDER BY nSales DESC
```

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: Why are you using a subquery at all? Why not a conditional aggregate? And yes, it'll count for all of the rows, that's what you've asked for; the sub query isn't correlated.

Comment: example starting data and desired results will help this greatly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation instead of a subquery.  I'm not sure what filter conditions you want applied, but something like this:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN sStatus = 'Closed' AND
                     dtFirstClosed > ?
                THEN nQuotetotal ELSE 0
           END) AS nsales,
       sCompany,
       MAX(CASE WHEN sStatus = 'Closed' AND
                     dtFirstClosed > ?
                THEN dtFirstClosed
           END) AS dtMostRecent,
       SUM(CASE WHEN sStatus = 'Open' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as  nOpenQuotes
FROM customer_quotes
WHERE sQuoteType = 'cam' AND
      bDeleted = 0
ORDER BY nSales DESC;
```

Note that the filter conditions in the `WHERE` clause apply to both open and closed quotes.

Comment: I think you want a MAX for dtMostRecent.

Answer (score 0):

**You can use a conditional window aggregate for this.** It needs to go in a derived table because the outer `WHERE` would otherwise exclude those rows.

It's unclear which of the `WHERE` predicates you want to affect the count, you may want to move some of them to the inner query.

> DO NOT inject data into your query, use *proper parameterization*

```sql
SELECT SUM(nQuotetotal) AS nsales,
       sCompany,
       MAX(dtFirstClosed) AS dtMostRecent,
       nOpenQuotes
FROM   (
    SELECT *,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN sStatus = 'Open' THEN 1 END)
         OVER (PARTITION BY sCompany) AS nOpenQuotes
    FROM customer_quotes
) cq
WHERE  sQuoteType = 'cam'
AND    bDeleted = 0
AND    sStatus = 'Closed'
AND    dtFirstClosed BETWEEN @dateFrom AND @dateTo
GROUP BY sCompany, nOpenQuotes
ORDER BY nSales DESC;
```